# Nginx rewrite downloading file

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a url with nginx but its downloading the php file instead of passing it

`https://www.example.com/s.php?k=7eqx6si58Mn4fBf8n9oiF9lwIQ%3D%3D&b=5`

Need to show as

`https://www.example.com/s/7eqx6si58Mn4fBf8n9oiF9lwIQ%3D%3D&b=5`

I tried the following  but its not working

```
location  ~ ^/s.php(.*)$ {
      rewrite ^/s/$ /s.php?k= last;
    }
```

I also have the following location block

```
location ~* \.php$ { 
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/www;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include  fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Your rewrite doesn't match the location, so it's not applied. So actually it's just location with empty body and defaults to download file.

Comment: @AlexeyTen you mean the order of the rewrite is wrong?

Comment: I mean that `^/s/$` regexp will never match `/s.php....`